# Replace text with automatically generated dates

Tags: bash, replace

I have a text file which looks like this

```
test tom
test fred
test harry
test jim
```

There are 12000 names in the text file.

I want to replace the word test with dates auto generated so it adds an extra hour to each name down the list. So I will end up with the following:

```
2015-04-10 14:00 tom
2015-04-10 15:00 fred
2015-04-10 16:00 harry
2015-04-10 17:00 jim
```

Once it reaches the end of the day it should continue to the next day and next month and year until the end.

How is this possible to do with a bash script?

Comment: You could use the `date` command. `date` can accept several input formats and convert them to a date-time output.

Comment: thanks but how exactly can this be done? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in a script and name it `whatever.sh`:

```
#/bin/bash

count=0

while read -r blah rest
do
    echo "$(date -d "+$count hours" +"%F %H:00") $rest"
    ((count++))
done
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x whatever.sh
```

And then:

```
./whatever.sh < input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits.  Wasn't aware of the `((var++))` shorthand.

Comment: No problem, you could even use `$((count++))` in the line above, although it is arguably more clear to do the two things separately.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{x=systime()}{$1=strftime("%F %H:00",x);x+=3600}1' file
```

#### Output

```
2015-04-10 14:00 tom
2015-04-10 15:00 fred
2015-04-10 16:00 harry
2015-04-10 17:00 jim
```